# Retrieve data from realtime firebase

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I have paths in database

```
routes
        route_id_1
        car_1
        id: "car1"
        departure: "..."
        cost: ...
        total_seats: ...
        available_seats: ...
        seats
        seat_id_1
        name: "seat1"
        // other seat properties
        seat_id_2
        name: "seat2"
        // other seat properties
        seat_id_3
        name: "seat3"
        // other seat properties
        car_2
        id: "car2"
        ...
        seats
        seat_id_1
        name: "seat1"
        // other seat properties
        seat_id_2
        name: "seat2"
        // other seat properties
        seat_id_3
        name: "seat3"
// other seat properties
```

i am able to fetch and display cars of specified route in car page but when i click one of the cars it should disply seats in that car but it says no available seats in this car which is the else part of this code

```
DatabaseReference seatsRef = mDatabase.child("routes").child(route).child(("seats") + (carId));
seatsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot seatSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Seat seat = seatSnapshot.getValue(Seat.class);
                seatList.add(seat);
            }
            seatsAdapter.setSeats(seatList);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SelectSeatActivity.this, "No seats available for this car", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: It's hard for us to say what's going on, as we can't see all values. It's more likely we can help if you run the code in the debugger yourself, and then tell us the result. So if you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).